# MVC 3 show hide Partial Views in jquery UI tabs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

In our application we are using Tabs to display the information for example contacts, in this tab the user can switch between view contacts and created contact. When the user clicks on ‘Create’ I want the partial view changed to CreateContact within the same tab. What is the best way to show hide a Partial Views in jquery UI tabs? Should I use Ajax code to do this?

View

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
   <li><a href="/Home/GetClaim">Claim</a></li>
   <li><a href="/Home/GetProduct">Products</a></li>
   <li><a href="/Home/GetContact">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult GetContact()
{
    return PartialView();
}

public ActionResult CreateContact()
{
    return PartialView();
}
```

Partial View

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Create", "Test", "Home")</li>
```

Thanks

Comment: Just to clarify: You have two tabs. One is to view created contacts, the other is to create a new contact. When someone creates a new contact, you want it to switch to the View Created Contact "View", not switch back the tabs.. is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use AJAX. That is in case you don't want to load all partial views at once.

If it doesn't matter, you can just render them at once:

```
<div id="tabs-1">
     @Html.Partial("GetClaim")
</div>
<div id="tabs-2">
     @Html.Partial("GetProduct")
</div>
<div id="tabs-3">
     @Html.Partial("GetClaim")
</div>
```

jQuery hides the elements that are not currently visible and will manage the switching automatically.

Comment: +1. Agreed. No need to even use ajax, since those actions don't do anything but render a partial (no data). So the action methods can be removed altogether.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Ajax.ActionLink() - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd493106.aspx

This will asynchronously submit your form to your controller method. If you set the AjaxOptions.InsertionMode to be AjaxOptions.InsertionMode.Replace then it will replace the partial view content with whatever you return from the controller. Then, you just need to return the GetContacts view in the creatcontacts controller action, as below:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetContact()
{
    return PartialView(RetrieveListOfContacts());
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateContact(StronglyTypedContactModel contact)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // .. write your contact here
        return PartialView("GetContact", RetrieveListOfContacts());
    }
    else
    {
        return PartialView(contact);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Also, you can specify that it be a GET request in the HttpMethod of the AjaxOptions, so as not to require form (as I originally assumed you did).